# Not showing video, only sounds when play real android device in react-native-video

Tags: android, react-native-video

I using react-native-video: 5.1.1, react-native: 0.63.3 . Writing code works in emulator but not showing video, only sound in android real device.

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        resizeMode="contain"
        source={{ uri: 'http://*****.mp4' }}
        style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 30, right: 0, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        controls
      />
</View>
```

Comment: Please share code that you have done

Answer (score 0):

I used to http url so I added to this code in AndroidManifest.xml. My problem fixed

```
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')
```